# Why is APC (PHP Accelerator) Only caching apc.php?

Tags: php

I installed PHP5,APC and XDEBUGGER with the install script found here:

[Dreamhost PHP+APC Install Instructions/Script](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Installing_PHP5#PHP_5.3_.2B_Xdebug_.2B_APC_install_script)

All systems seem to be working... except...

I added the apc.php to see the caching stats of APC (GUI Interface), and it showed that only apc.php file was being cached despite having installed wordpress and prestashop under the same domain, installing and running those php scripts.

I wonder if I did something wrong...

but my php5 is running as a cgi/fastcgi. I think I might have read somewhere about there being some issue with this. Not sure.

Any help is of coursed appreciated.

Comment: i think its because i dont have fastcgi setup properly =/

Comment: actually my php.cgi was compiled with --enable-fastcgi so i guess it is fcgi..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EUREKA... Aww found the solution here...

http://forum.dreamhosters.com/programming/48786-APC-installed-on-Dreamhost-It-was-done.htm